# Argue by contradiction : $n\in \mathbb N \to \; 4|(5^{n}-1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I was working for various method to solve this :$n\in \mathbb N \to \; 4|(5^{n}-1)$ now I want to solve it only by "Argue by contradiction"

Comment: if we need to prove it by contradiction, then wouldn't it be sufficient to consider the case to be false and then show it that at a specific position it is contradicted hence our assumption was false?

Comment: By contradiction? That doesn't sound like a natural way to prove that to me. It's easier to see directly: How does $5^n-1$ look in base $5$? Alternatively, compute $5^n-1$ modulo 4. Or prove it by **induction** on $n$. Are you confusing "contradiction" with "induction", perchance?

Comment: I know how to prove it by 10 various method ,but I need to prove it by contradiction

Comment: @khosrotash: Maybe you wanna  make a paper full of solutions! :D

Comment: @Henning Sometimes an OP is assigned to prove a conjecture using a one *specified* approach, (sometimes the assignment may require a student to prove, say, directly, and also by contradiction). Other approaches become irrelevant in such homework, though certainly worth knowing. I suspect this was an assigned task: "Prove X by contradiction."

Comment: Proof by contradiction: Suppose there were a smallest $n \geq 0$ such that $4 \nmid (5^n-1)$.  Since all $5^n$ are odd (no factors of $2$), we must have $5^n-1 = 4k+2$ for some $k$, or $5^n = 4k+3$.  Letting $k = 5i+j$ for some $i, j \geq 0$, we also have $5^n = 20i+4j+3$.  Since $5 \mid (4j+3), j = 3$, so $5^n = 20i+15$.  But then $5^{n-1} = 5^n/5 = 4i+3$, so we have a number $m < n$ (namely, $m = n-1$) such that $4i+3$ for some $i$—that is, for which $4$ does not divide $5^m-1$.  This is a contradiction, so there cannot be any $n$ such that $4$ does not divide $5^n-1$.

Comment: Is my question reopened  ?

Answer (score 10):

Assume that there exists a natural number $n$ such that $4\nmid (5^n-1)$. Let $n$ be smallest such number (i.e. $n=\min\{m|4\nmid (5^m-1)\}$ and since every non-empety subset of natural numbers contains a minimal element, $n$ is well defined). Since $4|5^1-1=4$, we have $n>1$. So, by our definition, $4|(5^{n-1}-1)$, but then $4|(5(5^{n-1}-1)+4)=5^n-1$ - a contradiction.

Comment: do you want to try this ? 5^n-1=4q +r and r={1,2,3}

Comment: That could also work, but you don't really need this: just follow my answer: if $4|t$ then $4|(5t+4)$ since $4|4$.

Comment: thank you ,your solution was great ! but I going to write a small paper on various method of solving ,and it is one of the problem.I will appreciate .

Answer (score 3):

As a reverse induction using contradiction:

Note that for $n=0$ you have $4|(1-1)$ and for $n=1$ you have $4|(5-1)$.

So **choose $m$ as the smallest positive integer** for which $4\not | (5^m-1)$

in which case $4\not | (5^m-1-4\times 5^{m-1})$ and so $4\not | (5^{m-1}-1)$

but by the definition of $m$ we know  $4 | (5^{m-1}-1)$, **leading to a contradiction**,

**implying there is no such $m$**

so  $4 | (5^n-1)$ for all positive integers $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\exists n\in\boldsymbol N\;\forall k\in\boldsymbol N\colon 4k\neq5^n-1$. Now consider $k=5^{n-1}+5^{n-2}+\cdots+1$.

Comment: would you please to explain it more ?!

Comment: @khosrotash, $5^{n-1} + 5^{n-2} + \cdots + 1 = \frac{5^n-1}{4}$.

Comment: @PeterPhipps Thank you. At khosrotash: remind that $4=5-1$.